An example of almost continuous function with respect to the Lebesgue measure but not continuous
I'm trying to construct a counterexample of a quasi-continuous but non-continuous function and it seemed like a good candidate to choose the Dirichlet function.
A function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is said to be $\textbf{almost continuous}$ with respect to the Lebesgue measure if for every $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists an open set $U \subset \mathbb{R}$ such that:

$\lambda(U) < \varepsilon$, where $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure;
The function $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R} \setminus U$.


Consider the Dirichlet function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined as:
$$
f(x) =
\begin{cases}
1, & \text{if } x \in \mathbb{Q}, \\
0, & \text{if } x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}.
\end{cases}
$$
This function is discontinuous everywhere.
Since $\mathbb{Q}$ is not an open set, we need to construct an open set that contains most of the rational numbers but has a small Lebesgue measure.
Given any $\varepsilon > 0$, we can cover each rational number $q_i \in \mathbb{Q}$ with an open interval $I_i = (q_i - \delta_i, q_i + \delta_i)$, where $\delta_i > 0$ is small enough such that:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \lambda(I_i) < \varepsilon.
$$
Let $U$ be the union of these intervals:
$$
U = \bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} I_i.
$$
The set $U$ is an open set and its Lebesgue measure is:
$$
\lambda(U) < \varepsilon.
$$

The set $\mathbb{R} \setminus U$ contains no rational numbers (or at least almost no rationals).
On this set, all points are irrational, and the Dirichlet function is constant (equal to zero) on all irrational numbers. Hence, on $\mathbb{R} \setminus U$, the function is continuous.
I'm not sure on how I take the open set that contains $\mathbb{Q}$, can I take a cover like that?
Is there an easier example?

$\mathbb Q$ is dense in $\mathbb R$ (for the usual topology). Therefore, if $U\subset \mathbb R$ is open and $\mathbb Q\subset U$, then $U=\mathbb R$.

@Kolakoski54 this is not true, for example $U = (-\infty, \pi) \cup (\pi, \infty)$.

If the way to choose $U$ is right, I think that my argument holds...or maybe am I doing something wrong?

Choose $f(x)=1$ if $x\geq 0$, zero otherwise, then choose $U=(-\varepsilon/2,\varepsilon/2)$.

Okay @Snoop, without much thought it seems to me that this is an easy example that works. But regarding mine, is there any problem with my assertions?

@SigmaAlgebra No, your proof is the classical one (I mean it is a common and well known construction).

@Yanko okay, thank you very much!

If you don't know it already, the following theorem might interest you: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lusin%27s_theorem
